# Merging unallocated disk space with ext4 (ubuntu installed)

Tags: partitioning

So I merged an 80 GB unallocated disk space to my Ubuntu partition in Windows Partition software (I came from windows environment), the merge is completed successfully, but when I check my disk size in my Ubuntu using Disks, the disk size increased but the 80 GB that I just merge is somehow occupied. It says 54% full. And I only have 73 GB of free space which was my previous free space before I merge. Basically I still have the amount of free space before and after I merge my disks.

Is there any way I can fix this?
[My disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmIXs.png)

Comment: How did you merge exactly? Did it resize the filesystem? Sounds like if the partition expanded in size, the filesystem didn't

Comment: You cannot resize a mounted partition.

Comment: found the solution, thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

sudo resize2fs [partition] solves my problem